# How do I get my Windows Service to keep running?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am trying to have a Windows service run all the time in the background of my computer with no-one knowing. My Windows service downloads the content of my email inbox and puts it in my database.

My Windows service just seams to stop - it enters a log every 60 seconds and then stops about 10 mins in?

I have posted my code below. Can any one see or tell me a reason why?

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;

namespace EmailWindowsService
{
    public partial class MyEmailService : ServiceBase
    {
        private DateTime lastRun;
        private bool flag = true;
        private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
        public MyEmailService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("MySource")) // every thing the windows service does is logged in server explorer
            {
                System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                    "MySource", "MyNewLog");
            }
            eventLogEmail.Source = "MySource";
            eventLogEmail.Log = "MyNewLog";

            // Timer Code
             aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1 * 60 * 1000); // 60 seconds
             aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
             aTimer.Enabled = true;
            // Timer Code
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            flag = true;
            lastRun = DateTime.Now;
            eventLogEmail.WriteEntry("Started");
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            eventLogEmail.WriteEntry("Stopped");
        }
        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            eventLogEmail.WriteEntry("Paused");
        }
        protected override void OnContinue()
        {    
            eventLogEmail.WriteEntry("Continuing");
        }
        protected override void OnShutdown()
        {
            eventLogEmail.WriteEntry("ShutDowned");
        }

        private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            RetriveEmailClass Emails = new RetriveEmailClass();
            if (flag == true)
            {
                eventLogEmail.WriteEntry("In getting Email Method");
                Emails.ServiceEmailMethod();
                lastRun = DateTime.Now;
                flag = false;
            }
            else if (flag == false)
            {
                if (lastRun.Date < DateTime.Now.Date)
                {
                    Emails.ServiceEmailMethod();
                    eventLogEmail.WriteEntry("In getting Email Method");
                }
            }
        }       
        }
    }
```

Comment: The reasons for a windows service to unexpectedly stop are: 1) Unhandled exception 2) someone shut it down. Now add exception handling to your code and see where your error is.

Comment: Put a `try-catch` in your code to debug the reason for it stopping.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm wrong, but do have you asked similar questions here before? Are you [Pomster](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1356321/pomster)? Then why create a new account? It is easier to help if we can see you questions in the context of your other questions. I apologize if I'm mistaken.

Comment: The System.Timers.Timer class is dangerous, it swallows exceptions thrown in the Elapsed event handler without a diagnostic.  You must use try/catch yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See that your class has no errors, an error there could throw you whole service out.
Also try putting your timer into a method and only call it, not have it in your service code.

A windows service should always be made as an empty shell that just call's methods.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of reasons that your Windows services stops running.

```
1. Unhandled exception in your code. Looking from you code snippet, please add exception handling in the OnTimedEvent() method.
2. You service may crashed for some reason. In this case, you can go to event viewer to find out the reason for the failure.
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have an unhandled exception. It's hidden since you use `System.Timers.Timer`. That timer eats all unhandled exceptions instead of letting them crash your app.

That means that your app might look like it's running OK while it's not. A try/catch in the timer callback will prove that.

I do recommend that you use `System.Threading.Timer` instead since it do not work in that way.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is straightforward enough except the source for your Emails.ServiceEmailMethod method. Does the method generate any exceptions? If so, they have not been trapped in your timer method. Try:

```
try { Emails.ServiceEmailMethod(); }  
catch (Exception ex) { eventLogEmail.WriteEntry(ex.Message); }
```